# Split one record into multiple rows based on dates. Procedure in Cursor sent error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to split one row into several, depending on some dates. I tried to create a procedure within cursor but failed. Seems I do not declare two variables but how should I fix the problem?

I have an original table (called Table1) as follows:

```
ID      DOB     Entry_date       Termination_date
1     2000-6-1       2010-9-1           2012-7-1
2     2004-12-1      2011-11-20         2013-2-1
```

Suppose these are the records of each student joining and leaving the school, with birthday date.

I need the records to be split into several, in order to calculate the number of days they attend school in each year, each age and each grade. Call this table Table2, which I have managed to produce using cursor:

```
ID  Year    Start_date  End_date
1   2010    2010-1-1    2010-6-1
1   2010    2010-6-1    2010-9-1
1   2010    2010-9-1    2010-12-31
1   2011    2011-1-1    2011-6-1
1   2011    2011-6-1    2011-9-1
1   2011    2011-9-1    2011-12-31
1   2012    2012-1-1    2012-6-1
1   2012    2011-6-1    2011-7-1
2   2011    2011-1-1    2011-11-20
2   2011    2011-11-20  2011-12-1
2   2011    2011-12-1   2011-12-31
2   2012    2012-1-1    2012-11-20
2   2012    2012-11-20  2012-12-1
2   2012    2012-12-1   2012-12-31
2   2013    2013-1-1    2013-2-1
```

However, now there is also a 3-month observation period from the entry date, call it Table3. The following is how Table3 should look like:

```
ID  Year    Start_date  End_date
1   2010    2010-1-1    2010-6-1
1   2010    2010-6-1    2010-9-1
1   2010    2010-9-1    2010-12-1
1   2010    2010-12-1   2010-12-31
1   2011    2011-1-1    2011-6-1
1   2011    2011-6-1    2011-9-1
1   2011    2011-9-1    2011-12-31
1   2012    2012-1-1    2012-6-1
1   2012    2011-6-1    2011-7-1
2   2011    2011-1-1    2011-11-20
2   2011    2011-11-20  2011-12-1
2   2011    2011-12-1   2011-12-31
2   2012    2012-1-1    2012-2-20
2   2012    2012-2-20   2012-11-20
2   2012    2012-11-20  2012-12-1
2   2012    2012-12-1   2012-12-31
2   2013    2013-1-1    2013-2-1
```

I am thinking of adding a procedure to replicate what I’ve done, but create a procedure before if @birthday>=@anniversary to judge whether the observation date is within each interval in table2 (but I wish to produce Table3 directly from Table1, without producing a redundant Table2). If not, just insert the record as before; else insert the record twice, one begins from start date but end at observation date; next one begins from observation date but end at end date.

I’ve tried the code as follows but failed.

```
create table [dbo].[table3] (ID int, Year int, Start_date date, End_date date)
declare @ID int,
   @DOB Date,
   @Entry_date date,
   @Termination_date date,
   @startyr int,
   @endyr int,
   @birthday date,
   @anniversary date,
   @date1 date,
   @date2 date

Declare cur1 cursor
For 
Select ID, DOB, Entry_date, Termination_date
From [dbo].[Table1];

Open cur1;
fetch next from cur1 into @ID, @DOB, @Entry_date, @Termination_date;
while  @@fetch_status=0
begin
set @startyr=year(@Entry_date);
set @endyr = year(@Termination_date);
set @obsdt=dateadd(day,90,@Entry_date);
while @startYr<=@EndYr
begin
set @birthday=datefromparts(@startyr,month(DOB),day(DOB));
set @anniversay= datefromparts(@startyr,month(Entry_date),day(Entry_date));
set @date1= datefromparts(@startYr,1,1);
    set @date2 = case when datefromparts(@startYr,12,31)>@Termination_date then @Termination_date else datefromparts(@startYr,12,31) end;


create procedure dbo.test(@begindt date, @stopdt date)
as
if (@begindt>@ obsdt) and (@stopdt<@obsdt)
begin
insert into [dbo].[table3] (ID, Year, Start_date, End_date) values (@ID, @startyr, @ begindt, @obsdt);
insert into [dbo].[table3] (ID, Year, Start_date, End_date) values (@ID, @startyr, @ obsdt, @stopdt);
end
else 
insert into [dbo].[table3] (ID, Year, Start_date, End_date) values (@ID, @startyr, @ begindt, @ stopdt);

if @birthday>=@anniversary
        begin
            exec [dbo].[test] @date1, @ anniversary
            exec [dbo].[test] @anniversary, @birthday
            exec [dbo].[test] @birthday, @date2
        end

    else
        begin
            exec [dbo].[test] @date1, @birthday
            exec [dbo].[test] @birthday, @anniversary
            exec [dbo].[test] @anniversary, @date2
        end

    set @startYr=@startYr+1
end

fetch next from cur1 into @ID, @DOB, @Entry_date, @Termination_date;

end
close cur1
go
```

The error message is as follows:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'procedure'.
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@begindt".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@stopdt".

Comment: Failed, you say.  Any details on the error message?

Comment: Sorry for still struggling with editing thread... It is not the exact table I used, but I guess the problems are similar:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'procedure'. Must declare the scalar variable "@begindt". Must declare the scalar variable "@stopdt".

Comment: Can you please post the error message

Comment: I think you need to understand what a procedure is. Its not a local function, its a procedure that would be used by other procedures or queries. If you take out your create procedure part you will be closer to what you want. Then you just need to get rid of the cursor which is also not necessary.

Comment: Also, please post the expected results to make it clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you TomC. I add Table2 as well to clarify the question. Take out create procedure part enables me to create Table2, but I still haven't figured out how to produce table2 without cursor. I guess generate Table3 from a readily made Table2 is much easier. You are correct, I am still new with SQl and haven't understand the nature of many things...

Comment: @fanfan I have updated an answer I had once I understood the requirement. At least I think I understand. Please clarify if not.

Comment: @TomC Thank you so much for your answer! It's really genius! It is just that I haven't got time to fully understand the code, but from the result, it's exactly what I want and your method realises it much better than what I wished for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - After understanding what yuo were actually trying to achieve I updated the query I wrote.

The following is your script recreated without a create procedure, and without a cursor. As a general rule, if you ever think you need a cursor in sql server, you are probably wrong 99.9% of the time.

The following query goes through multiple CTEs, its done this way to make it simple to understand, and could no doubt be simplified further.

You will see that I am first expanding your table into 1 row per year, then setting the anniversaries for each row.

I then expand it into one row per date so that I can sort them simply, and then discard any dates that are outside the enrolment range or not required for the year, and finally pair them up into ranges.

```
;With daterange as (
    Select year(min(Entry_date)) as y1, year(max(Termination_date)) as y2 from table1
),
-- Expand the rows into 1 per year
years as
(
    Select y1 as y from daterange
    union all
    Select y + 1
    from years
    where y <= (select y2 from daterange)
) 
-- Now work our all the birthdays, anniversaries etc for each source row and each applicable year
, alldates as 
(
    Select table1.*, 
        dateadd(day,90,Entry_date) obsdt, 
        datefromparts(y,month(DOB),day(DOB)) as birthday,
        datefromparts(y,month(Entry_date),day(Entry_date)) as anniversary,
        datefromparts(y,1,1) date1,
        datefromparts(y,12,31) date2,
        y
    From table1
    join years on y between year(Entry_Date) and year(Termination_date)
)
-- There are 7 possible dates - year start, birthday, anniversay, obsdt, year end, entry, termination
, dates as 
(
   select d from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) as starts(d)
)
-- Split it into multiple rows so we can sort the dates
, expanded as
(
    select ID, y, entry_date, termination_date, 
        case d 
            when 1 then date1 
            when 2 then birthday 
            when 3 then anniversary 
            when 4 then obsdt 
            when 5 then date2 
            when 6 then entry_date 
            when 7 then termination_date 
        end as dt
    from alldates
    cross join dates
)
-- Exclude rows that are not from the year - entry, termination, obsdt, or are outside the entry/termination dates
, validrows as
(
    select distinct ID, y, dt
    from expanded 
    where year(dt)=y
    and dt>=entry_date and dt<=termination_date
)
-- Pair each ro with its next row
, pairs as 
(
    select *, lead(dt,1) over(partition by ID,Y order by dt) as dt2
    from validrows 
)
-- The final insert
insert into [dbo].[table3] (ID, Year, Start_date, End_date)
select ID, y, dt, dt2
from pairs where dt2 is not null
order by ID, y, dt
```

The result of this is:

```
ID  y       dt          dt2
1   2010    2010-09-01  2010-11-30
1   2010    2010-11-30  2010-12-31
1   2011    2011-01-01  2011-06-01
1   2011    2011-06-01  2011-09-01
1   2011    2011-09-01  2011-12-31
1   2012    2012-01-01  2012-06-01
1   2012    2012-06-01  2012-07-01
2   2011    2011-11-20  2011-12-01
2   2011    2011-12-01  2011-12-31
2   2012    2012-01-01  2012-02-18
2   2012    2012-02-18  2012-11-20
2   2012    2012-11-20  2012-12-01
2   2012    2012-12-01  2012-12-31
2   2013    2013-01-01  2013-02-01
```